# Downcasting wondering in c++

Tags: c++, g++

I have the next code

```
class Shape 
{
public:
    virtual Shape* create()     { return new Shape; }
    virtual void print()        { cout << "Shape" << endl; }
    virtual ~Shape()            {}
};

class Circle : public Shape 
{
public:
    virtual Circle* create()        { return new Circle; }
    virtual void print()            { cout << "Circle" << endl; }
};

void  foo  () 
{ 
    Shape*  sp  = new Circle;
    Circle* cp  = sp->create();  
    cp->print();
    delete sp;
    delete cp;
}
```

The code is not compiling because Shape is not a Circle(downcasting error).

I am a little confused. The create() is not dynamic binding? the line

```
Circle* cp  = sp->create();
```

not suppose to return a Circule*?

Answer (score 2):

It's because that line

`Circle* cp  = sp->create();`

is evaluated at compile time by the compiler. And at compile time all it knows is that `sp` is a pointer to `Shape` therefore the signature for `Shape::create()` is used at compile time. It can't know what the pointer is pointing to because that is allocated and set at runtime. To get around it use a `dynamic_cast`.

`Circle* cp  = dynamic_cast<Circle*>(sp->create());`

Answer (score 1):

Downcasting is not implicit. Since you know what you are doing(i.e. `sp` is actually a `circle`), use `dynamic_Cast`

```
Circle* cp  = dynamic_cast<Circle*>(sp->create());
```

Answer (score 1):

You invoke `create()` on an instance that has the static type `Shape`. Hence, the function signature is `Shape* create()`. Indeed, after vtable lookup, the actual function invoked is `Circle::create()`, but the point of storing a `Circle` instance as a `Shape` reference is hiding the concrete type, its member functions and together with that possible covariant return types.

To obtain a `Circle` object via `Circle::create()`, you can either

```
Circle *c1 = new Circle; // Static type info (Circle) is preserved
Circle *c2 = c1->create();  // Ok, the covariant return type is Circle*
```

or

```
Shape *s1 = new Circle; // Everything Circle-related lost on the lhs
Circle *c1 = dynamic_cast<Circle*>(s1->create()); // Manually restore with RTTI
```

though the latter is rather a hint that something is wrong (why would you need to create subclass instances from a base class interface without hiding their concrete type?).

As a side note, you could also consider changing the function signature such that it returns a `std::unique_ptr<Shape>` or `std::unique_ptr<Circle>`, which is good practice for factory functions that return polymorphic class instances.

Answer (score 0):

Cast the shape pointer to a circle.

```
Circle* cp  = (Circle* sp)->create();
```